# Cant use plotly in Jupyter

Tags: python, plotly

Hi guys Im trying to use plotly to create a graph and it doesn't work either in Jypiter conda root or default. Any idea? 
My code has been:

```
    import plotly.plotly as py
    from plotly.graph_objs import *
    py.sign_in('username', 'api_key')
```

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate on your problem more? If you are using Jupyter, make sure you're making your Python notebook in the same directory that has the data file you want to graph. (Or use additional code to navigate to the proper directory.)

I'd recommend using Pandas, a library that gives support for dataframes/series, in order to store your data easily, and then plot it with plotly. Their documentation is pretty good, but (and this is taken from their tutorial), here is how to make a bar graph, assuming you've already loaded your data into the dataframe "df":

```
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import *

data = [Bar(x=df.School,
        y=df.gap)]

py.iplot(data, filename='jupyter/basic_bar')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend uninstalling plotly and reinstalling via pip `python -m pip install plotly` on the same python environment you are running Jupyter on. Pip3 also works if using Python 3.

This will automatically add it to the path.

Comment: do you have pip installed / usable?

Comment: tried to.. but didnt actually, do you now the easiest way to do so?

Comment: If you are running Ubuntu:
`sudo apt install python-pip`

If Windows: 
should come preinstalled if you have a new version of Python 2 or 3 but https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/ may help